# Captcha based on image rotation implemented somewhere?

Tags: image-processing, captcha

Having read google's paper from 09 [1] about captchas based on image rotation I wonder if they are implemented somewhere. Did anybody see an actual system which uses them? (I haven't created a google account in a while, but I think they still use "normal" captchas)

http://research.google.com/pubs/archive/35157.pdf

Comment: you've got to collect enough image to get enough entropy for your captchas, which is at the end less than what you can generate with text. Plus some image could be tricky and generate false positive, that would obviously require some human screening to validate them, I don't think they are using it.

Comment: Are you sure you can't do it w/o human interaction? What about let humans verify a set of let's say 500 pictures, then always display two pictures (from which we know that one is verified) and add a button "It's not obvious to find the pictures position" we then use the picture already verified to decided weather to let the user in or not and assume the rotation of the second image correct if the verified image is correctly rotated. This would enable us to grow the size of our verified image set.

Comment: I've been wondering about this myself, however I doubt the success and applicability. Interestingly, I did not know the Google Paper you've mentioned but this CGI paper from 2010 where I first heard of this idea (but they cite the google paper, just checked): http://springerlink.metapress.com/content/m0148321v2523v8r/